# NSDate and time interval issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsdate

I am trying to convert a NSString into a double using the following:

```
double lastSynced;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
               [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"];
               NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
               dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2012-03-28 18:41:25"];
               lastSynced = [dateFromString timeIntervalSince1970];
```

However when printing lastSynced it always gives me 0. Why is this?

Comment: You're leaking the initial assignment to `dateFromString`. You don't need to `alloc`/`init` an object there; just assign the result of `[dateFormatter dateFromString:]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date format is wrong. Should be:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

instead of:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"];
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting strings are not correct. You should use :

`[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];`

Good luck !